# give link to a view in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to give links to different pages in the menu bar. I've created views for the page and corresponding controller is created. Also code for menu bar is written separately in another view. In this view I am trying to give link. I tried giving link with `base_url()`, but when the page loads links after the link which I given href is not working. I tried:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admember/index">
```

Here, **admember** is controller and **index** is my function.

My code:

header.php

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="home.php">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-dropdown classic-menu-dropdown ">
                    <a data-hover="megamenu-dropdown" data-close-others="true" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript:;">
                    Memeber Management <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-left">
                        <li class=" dropdown-submenu">
                            <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admember/index">
                            <i class="icon-briefcase"></i>
                            Add Member </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class=" dropdown-submenu">
                            <a href=":;">
                            <i class="icon-wallet"></i>
                            Edit Member </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class=" dropdown-submenu">
                            <a href=":;">
                            <i class="icon-bar-chart"></i>
                            Delete Memeber </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
</ul>
```

Controller admember.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class admember extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('addmember');
}
}
```

Can anyone help me with this. I'm a newbie in codeigniter.

Comment: well what is the rendered link?

Comment: check what URL is generating in Firfox with firebug enabled in your dropdown

Comment: not working means any error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to load $this->load->helper('url'); and think problem in  base url in Codeginter.
Go to application->config->config.php and change base url example as `http://yourbaseurl/`

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The problem was with `$this->load->helper('url');`. Now its working.